# Property 'hash' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: jquery, hash

I am using jquery 2.1.1 and have run into this error

> Property 'hash' does not exist on type 'Element'

While trying to do this

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', (e) => {    
    var hash = e.target.hash;   
});
```

Has hash been depricated? What to use instead?

I've also tried e.currentTarget.hash which didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe you want the `href` property since it is an anchor element...

Comment: `hash` only exists on the `location` object. What behaviour are you expecting here?

Comment: You wanna use `e.target.getAttribute('href').hash`?

Comment: @callback 'hash' does not exist on type 'string'